# Fetch Schedule data from a BigQuery Table to another BigQuery Table (Scheduled queries)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

I am really new to `GCP` and I am trying to `Query` in a `GCP BigQuery` to fetch all data from one `BigQuery table` and Insert all into `another BigQuery table`

I am trying the Following query where `Project 1` & `Dataset.Table1` is the Project where I am trying to read the data. and `Project 2` and `Dataset2.Table2` is the Table where I am trying to Insert all the data with the same Naming

```
SELECT * FROM `Project1.DataSet1.Table1` LIMIT 1000
insert  INTO `Project2.Dataset2.Table2`
```

But am I receiving a query error message?

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a couple of comments...

1. The syntax might be different => `insert into table select` and so on - see [DML statements in the standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax)
2. Such approach of data coping might not be very optimal considering time and cost. It might be better to use `bq cp -f ...` commands - see [BigQuery Copy — How to copy data efficiently between BigQuery environments](https://medium.com/@vmnamburu/how-to-efficiently-copy-data-between-bigquery-environments-part-1-475df9c6cac6) and [bq command-line tool reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_cp) - if that is possible in your case.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax of the query is as suggested by @al-dann.  I will try to explain further with a sample query as below:

**Query**:

```
insert into `Project2.Dataset2.Table2`
select * from `Project1.DataSet1.Table1`
```

**Input Table**:

[image]

This will insert values into the second table as below:

**Output Table**:

[image]